# mvc procedure question

Tags: php, model-view-controller, forms, breadcrumbs

I am borrowing some codeigniter authentication library and try to integrate it with my mvc version.
My version initiates breadcrums in the basecontroller and every module has it's own
controller that extends it.

What I want to know is if I am submitting my login form, then my submit action
will be /controller/function.
But, **I don't want the function to appear in the breadcrumbs**, how is this normally done.
As I am writing this, I am thinking that I can run all the logic threw the default
index function.

On the other hand, you want to be able to call on functions directly.

**The question is how this is normally done in an mvc architecture**
Could someone give me some feedback on this, please.

thanks, Richard

Comment: What *do* you want in the breadcrumbs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you authenticate are you redirecting the user to where they were previously or the index page on the website?

Usually the login controller doesn't actually have a view, it just authenticates and forwards you to either the login form if you are not authenticated, or a logged in page if the person is authenticated.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late response I have a loginview page, the breadcrumbs will show login, because that is the controller and it is running the default indexfunction. But what do I do when I want to proces the form. I don't want it to show login>>proceslogin because that is what it is doing now.What are my possibilitys? I do want to redirect, when it is ok, but it is not ok to show the login functions as if they where links for navigation.Navigation should only show different pages.

Comment: I wil run it threw the index function, that seems to be the most logical for know.

Comment: Also, mmy logincontroller has the loginform as a view, but I see your point